# jQuery UI tabs and external links

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-tabs

I am having a problem with getting my jQuery ui tabs to link to an external HTML document, also does the external HTML document have to be in the same format or should it just be body content?

The problem I saw on firefox console was that tags were mismatched and those tags were `</head>` and `</head>` which made no sense at all.

Here is what the HTML looks like.

```
<div id = "tabs">
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#policyInfo">Policy Details</a></li>
    <li><a href="editPolicy.html">Edit Policy</a></li> <!-- My problem lies here -->
    <li><a href="#personalInfo">Personal Details</a></li>
 </ul>
...
```

This is what my jQuery looks like at the moment.

```
$(function() {
            $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

**In summary**: I don't know how to link a tab to an external webpage. I have tried the AJAX example posted on the jQueryUI website.

Comment: I think we're going need a few more clues to work with...

Comment: please post more relevant code and describe the problem further so we can help ...

Comment: @PerryW is this enough information now?

Comment: I am not sure you can use href="$tag" in jqueryUI tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you getting error. are you sure you have correct file mentioned in the href ? it exists ?  [JqueryUI Ajax tab](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax)

```
<div id="tabs"> 
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#policyInfo">Policy Details</a></li>
    <li><a href="editPolicy.html">Edit Policy</a></li> <!-- My problem lies here -->
    <li><a href="#personalInfo">Personal Details</a></li>
  </ul>
 <div id="policyInfo">
    <p>asdf</p>
  </div>
  <div id="personalInfo">
    <p>asdf</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Jquery.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
      beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.jqXHR.error(function() {
          ui.panel.html(
            "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
            "If this wouldn't be a demo." ); 
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

if you got any error ? then may be your href location is not valid.

Comment: Yeah the page does exist, although like I mentioned earlier there was a tag mismatch. does the external page have to have the whole skeleton or just the body tags?

Comment: @SnakeEater External file should have whole skeletone. <html><head></head><body></body></html>